# Jquery Image Cycler

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to make an image cycler thing for my website with jQuery, but I can't get it to cycle through.I want to add three buttons that will cycle through the pictures, button1 = first picture, button2= second picture, etc... AND have it cycle through automaticaly every 5 seconds or so if the buttons are not clicked, how would I do this. I've searched for a solution, with no luck. Help would be much appreciated.
My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var current = 1
if(current == 1){
    $('.imgslide1').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide2').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide3').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide1').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut().curr();
};
if(current == 2){
    $('.imgslide1').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide2').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide3').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide2').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut().curr();
};
if(current == 3){
    $('.imgslide1').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide2').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide3').fadeOut();
    $('.imgslide3').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut().curr();
};
if(current > 3){
    current = 1;
};
function curr(){
    current++;
};
$('#button1').click(function() {
    current = 1
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
    current = 2
});
$('#button3').click(function() {
    current = 3
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you want a custom one? There are a number of jQuery plugins and libraries available. I have used [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider/) in the past. It's very simplistic and isn't very large, so there's virtually no impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using Jquery, check out slidejs.com for a more comprehensive example with code you can use.

```
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                hoverPause: true,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:-35
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see other people have posted some suggestions. I'd just like to share an absolutely awesome plugin that I've used in numerous projects.

It's called Cycle and you can read more about it here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It supports nav (1, 2, 3), next, previous, custom callbacks and a lot more. Check out some of the very simple demos.

(I've tested MANY cycle-plugins and this is the best one I've come across).